# Should I use the Django admin for user submitted content?

Tags: django

I'm creating a site that will allow users to authenticate via Facebook and create content.

Should I use the Django admin interface for content creation or would it be smarter to create my own interface. If I should roll my own are there any good tutorials about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use admin login page and with custom URL redirection. Here is the working example for facebook authentication.
https://github.com/sivaa/django-social-auth-facebook

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, but I'm more curious about content creation forms and if it's a best practice for random users to use the admin interface to create content.

Comment: you can restrict the user's default permissions(from a pre-defined group). Whenever new user logins, assign a default user group. I have developed very similar example. You can refer it here. https://github.com/sivaa/pycon2012-todo

Comment: I don't want to spend much time in spending UI screens unless it is absolutely necessary. I always try to customize the admin page itself. The recent app which I have develped. http://myeventsin.appspot.com

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, the django admin is best for validating your models during development and testing; and should not be used as a front end user interface.

Since each site/application has their own unique requirements, it is difficult to recommend a tutorial. Once you are familiar with django, you will find the following libraries helpful:

- [`django-bootstrap-toolkit`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit) - this integrates the the excellent [bootstrap css/javascript framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in django.
- [`django-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) - allows your users to login using their social network credentials.
- [`pinax` project](http://pinaxproject.com/) - a collection of common utilities for developing just about any kind of front end website.

For customizing the existing admin application:

- [`grappelli`](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) - a custom skin for the admin
- [`django-frontendadmin`](https://github.com/bartTC/django-frontendadmin) - edit models in the front end using template tags
- [`django-admin-tools`](https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/wiki/Home) - customized widgets and UI elements for the admin application

Comment: Hmm...I see what you're saying, but this is an area that seems to be glossed over fairly often. The Django book I have is twice as thick as my Rails book, but only talks about forms in relations to search boxes and contact forms. For all content creation/editing it uses the admin interface, though in my Rails book is talks extensively about content creation/updating forms.

I know how easy it is to muddle though and find things that work but aren't ideal. I just want something so I know I'm not going totally down the wrong road.

Comment: That's because the contributed app from django is on of its strengths; vs. whatever comes with rails (I think just plain scaffolding, if that).